# Proving a subsequence doesn't converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When I want to prove that a sequence  doesn't converge by showing that it's subsequence doesn't converge , can i use the limit comparison test? (Usually used for series) .

for example -

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{1}{3n+1}
$$
when $N  \rightarrow \infty $

Answer (score 1):

$$
 \frac{1}{3n+1}>\frac{1}{3(n+1)}
$$
$\displaystyle \frac13 \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{1}{(n+1)}→∞$ , therefore that subsequence is diverge.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that convergence of the sequence $\sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{1}{3n+1}$ is, by definition, *equivalent to* convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3n+1}$, as you can verify by looking up the definition of convergence of series in any textbook.

So when you apply the limit comparison test for series to conclude that the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{3n+1}$ does not converge, that conclusion is *equivalent to* saying that the sequence $\sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{1}{3n+1}$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not entirely clear, but I assume this is what you meant by "limit comparison":

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{1}{3n + 1} \leq 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{3n} = 1 + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}
$$

and so

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{N \to \infty} 1 + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{1}{3n + 1} \rightarrow \infty
$$

This same principle can be applied to sequences as well.  For example, suppose we have two infinite sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$, and suppose we know that for $n \rightarrow \infty$, the terms $ b_n \rightarrow \infty$.  Now if $\exists$ some number M suitably large so that for all $n > M$, $|a_n| \geq |b_n|$, then the sequence $\{a_n\}$ also diverges.

Comment: When $n=0, \frac{1}{0}.$

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Thanks for the catch!  I edited the answer

Comment: Please see the condition and result of the test, here is the reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test